# MoviePy - proper way to position text

Tags: python, moviepy

I'go got a fullhd (1980x1080) movie clip with background image and two text lines

all lines are horizontally centered
one line should be vertically centered in first half of image
and second line in the bottom half of image.

like that:
[image]

Here is the code

```
image_clip = ImageClip("background_image.png", duration=4)

one_text = TextClip("One text".encode('utf-8'), fontsize=250, color='MediumGoldenRod', font="Arial-Unicode-MS")
start_x = 1920/2 - one_text.size[0]/2
start_y = 1080/2 - one_text.size[1] - 100
character_word = one_text.set_pos(('center','center')).set_position((start_x, start_y))

two_text = TextClip("Two Text".encode('utf-8'), fontsize=250, color='MediumGoldenRod', font="Arial-Unicode-MS")
start_x = 1920/2 - two_text.size[0]/2
start_y = 1080/2 - two_text.size[1] - 100
character_word = two_text.set_pos(('center','center')).set_position((start_x, start_y))

current_clip = CompositeVideoClip([image_clip,one_text,two_text])
```

My thoughts that there is something with textclip's relative positions.

Comment: What is the problem ? you did not ask a question here.

Comment: The problem is that text position not like i wanna and i can't find the reason for that